# There exists a homomorphism $f : G \to H$ with $|G| = 20$ and $|im f | = 6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

> There exists a homomorphism $f : G \to H$ with $|G| = 20$ and $|im f | = 6$?

Is this true? I know that I have to use the first isomorphism theorem but I don't know what to do next?

Comment: :I don't undrestand what means $f : G ! H$ with $|G| = 20$

Comment: do you means $f:G\to H$?

Comment: yeah. thats what i meant?

Comment: @user2304063:I'm say this means of $f : G ! H$ is $f:G\to H$?

Comment: yeh. thats what i meant to write. thanks

Comment: @user230462:use this,suppose $G_1$and$G_2$ two groups and$f:G_1\to G_2$ is homomorphism and order of $G_1$ is finite then  $|im f |$divide order of $G_1$

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: the first isomorphism theorem tells you that $|\text{im}(f)|$ is equal to the index in $G$ of $\ker f$.

Comment: so what is the ker f?

Comment: @user230463 Do you know Lagrange's theorem?

Comment: @user230463 $\ker f:=\{x\in G:f(x)=e\}$, if you mean that you aren't familiar with the notation.

Comment: since the index of G doesn't equal to the |im(f)| this statement is false.

Comment: By FHT $[G:\text{ker}(f)]=|G|/|\text{ker}(f)|=|\text{Im}(f)| \Rightarrow 20/|\text{ker}(f)|=6$. Hence no such map exists.

Comment: My statement says "[the index in $G$ of $\ker f$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_a_subgroup)", @user230463

Comment: @user230463:index and order are not same mean